# Can anyone suggest a good but simple Open Source Rails project with lot of pending features to contribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, open-source

Can anyone suggest me a good RoR open source project that covers a lot of Rails fundamentals but yet is simple, and most importantly has lot of features or atleast bug fixes that are yet to be implemented? I checked out a few like Spree, Substruct, etc. but could not zero in upon one, that is simple and has features to develop. I am not sure if any of them even had list of bugs to be fixed., though features will be better.

Answer (score 3):

Check [Diaspora](http://diasporaproject.org/), this is the [Diaspora Github](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora) page.

Here is the List of open [Issues](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/issues)

Here is the Diaspora [Installation Guide](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/wiki/Notes-on-Installing-and-Running-Diaspora)